# how can i show icons in menu when users hover on it?

Tags: html, css, menu

I have a HTML and CSS menu and I wanna show the special icon for each item when users hover on each item. I will show you my menu and codes...

```css
       .nav{
            background-color: #4f9b30;
        }

        .nav a {
          display: inline-block;
          color: black;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 14px;
          text-decoration: none;
          font-size: 17px;
          border-radius: 5px;
          
        }
        .nav a:hover {
          background-color: #ff5c00;
          color: black;
        }


        .home:hover{
            background-image: url(https://ittest.ir/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/home-1.png);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
```

```html
        <body>
            <div class="nav">
                <a class="home" href="#">Home</a>
                <a class="ran" href="#">why iran</a>
                <a class="blog" href="#">blog</a>
                <a class="services" href="#">About</a>
                <a class="news"href="#">News</a>
                <a class="event" href="#">event</a>
                <a class="invest" href="#">invest</a>
                <a class="contact" href="#">Contact</a>

              </div>
        </body>
```

this is my html and css codes

Comment: Actually, i wanna add icons on my items while hover, I mean when a user hovers on HOME, a home icon appears there. but I don't know how should I do it.

Comment: what CSS code can help me to do it well. I could add just home icon but the position is not correct.

Comment: For example you can add `background-position:top center;`  to your `.home:hover`

Comment: Thanks a lot. can I hide the "home" word then? I mean when users hover on this item, home icon appears, and the "home" word disappears. is it possible?

Comment: if you use a span yes.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using a background image, you can adjust it's position using `background-position`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position.

You can adjust `padding-left` on `.nav a` to add space from the left edge and the nav text.

```css
.nav{
  background-color: #4f9b30;
}

.nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 25px 14px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-radius: 5px;

}
.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #ff5c00;
  color: black;
}


.home:hover{
    background-image: url(https://ittest.ir/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/home-1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 4% 44%;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <a class="home" href="#">Home</a>
    <a class="ran" href="#">why iran</a>
    <a class="blog" href="#">blog</a>
    <a class="services" href="#">About</a>
    <a class="news"href="#">News</a>
    <a class="event" href="#">event</a>
    <a class="invest" href="#">invest</a>
    <a class="contact" href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah, I've checked your link and I got it. thank you a lot

Comment: @MohammadNajafi Good to know. Feel free to accept this answer in case someone else comes looking for a similar answer. Thanks!